# How to copy and append cells content from a different workbook to an Activework?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro that allows a user to browse and select multiple Excel files, after the user has selected the multiple Excel files, the content from multiple Excel files should be saved on the current active workbook, on one sheet. the content would be append one another.

The problem is that when the loop runs for the second time it complains with the range, it says the range should start at "A1".

here is my code below.

```
Sub Button3_Click()
Dim fileStr As Variant
Dim incount As Integer
Dim wbk1 As Workbook, wbk2 As Workbook

incount = 1

fileStr = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="microsoft excel files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx", Title:="Get File", MultiSelect:=True)

    For i = 1 To UBound(fileStr)
        MsgBox fileStr(i), , GetFileName(CStr(fileStr(i)))
        Set wbk1 = ActiveWorkbook
        Set wbk2 = Workbooks.Open(fileStr(i))

        wbk2.Sheets(1).Cells.Copy wbk1.Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(incount, 1)

        incount = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        wbk2.Close
    Next i

    MsgBox incount

End Sub
Function GetFileName(fileStr As String)
    Dim fso As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    GetFileName = fso.GetFileName(fileStr)

End Function
```

Error message:

```
Run-time error '1004'

To paste all cells from an Excel worksheet into the current worksheet,
you must paste into the first cell(A1 or R1C1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *cells.copy* copies the whole sheet of data to the row of 'incount' which means that there is not room on the destination for the 'whole source sheet' below the already pasted data

Try the following code which removes incount and just picks up the UsedRange:

```
Sub Button3_Click()
Dim fileStr As Variant
Dim wbk1 As Workbook, wbk2 As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet

fileStr = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="microsoft excel files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx", Title:="Get File", MultiSelect:=True)

Set wbk1 = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws1 = wbk1.Sheets("Sheet3")

For i = 1 To UBound(fileStr)
    MsgBox fileStr(i), , GetFileName(CStr(fileStr(i)))

    Set wbk2 = Workbooks.Open(fileStr(i))

    wbk2.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Copy ws1.Cells(ws1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 1)
    wbk2.Close
Next i

End Sub
Function GetFileName(fileStr As String)
    Dim fso As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    GetFileName = fso.GetFileName(fileStr)
End Function
```

Comment: I'm getting this error:

Run-time error '9'

Subscript out of range

Comment: have you removed incount completely, or do you now have the error on the 'msgbox incount'? if not there, where does the error occur?

Comment: Removed incount everywhere as u said, I get the error on the line you gave me. Thanx

Comment: Ok thanx. will test it and get back to you